# How to get the inmediate child directory of a file path in Java?

Tags: java, path, filesystems, nio

I want to navigate the file system and get the path to the child of a directory (if exists) without the root.

For example:

- Input:  `Users/Documents/SVG`
- Output: `Documents/SVG`

My solution so far is to hardcode a string manipulation of the path:

```java
  /**
   * Return the path to the immediate child of a directory.
   *
   * @param path to a directory
   * @return path to the child without the root
   */
  public static String removeRootFolderInPath(String path) {
    ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(path.split("/")));
    if (tmp.size() > 1) {
      tmp.remove(0);
    }
    path = String.join("/", tmp);
    return path;
  }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Path.relativize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)) can help

```
  Path
  parent=Path.of("Users"),
  child=Path.of("Users","Documents","SVG");

  Path relative=parent.relativize(child);
```

You can convert this Path back to an [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile()) as follows

```
relative.toFile()
```

And you can concert any File to an Path as [follows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toPath())

```
File f=...
Path p=f.toPath();
```

For better operations on files take a look at the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Path.subpath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#subpath(int,int)).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strPath = "Users\\Documents\\SVG";
    System.out.println(getChild(strPath));
}

public static Path getChild(String str) {
    Path path = Path.of(str);
    if (path.getNameCount() < 1) { // impossible to extract child's path
        throw new MyException();
    }
    return path.subpath(1, path.getNameCount());
}
```

**Output**

```
Documents\SVG
```